# Does Google Cloud Speech API save my sound recordings?

Tags: java, android, api, cloud, speech

I want to use Google Cloud Speech API for clinical purposes.
It is important to know, if Google Cloud Speech save my sound recordings?

Does anyone know that?
I am very thankful for answers!

Greeting 
Melanie

Comment: only they know for sure if they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To help Cloud Speech-to-Text to better suit your needs, you can opt into the data logging program. The data logging program allows Google to improve the quality of Speech-to-Text through using customer data to refine its speech recognition service. As a benefit for opting in, you gain access to enhanced transcription models that Google has trained by using data collected through the data logging program.

So yes, to improve its service, it might keeping track of your data (even if anonymously).

> Your data collected through data logging enjoys the same level of security as all other Google Cloud services. The Google security model is an end-to-end process, built over 15 years of experience and focused on keeping customers safe on Google applications like Gmail, Search and other Apps.

I won't go deeper into this since this is a legal-related question and maybe hasn't its place on this site.

> For more information about Google's security policies, see the Google Cloud security whitepaper.